# hostvars 'list object' has no attribute

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, hostvars

I am trying to get some result from the hostvars , but fails.

playbook:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars[item]['a']}}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

results:

```
ok: [ansible8] => (item=ansible8) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_job_id": "921062922128.33800",
            "attempts": 1,
            "end": "2021-09-16 05:39:47.335977",
             blah blah
            "start": "2021-09-16 05:39:46.323621"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [ansible8] => (item=ansible7) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_job_id": "688007320452.57867",
            "attempts": 1,
            "end": "2021-04-03 22:12:40.249637",
             blah blah
            "start": "2021-04-03 22:12:39.241665"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, i would like to get the a.start and a.end, so my playbook like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars[item]['a']['start']}}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

But apparently it didn't work, and got the error msg

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute  'start'

Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: The error message is clear `'list object' has no attribute  'start'`. The variable `a` keeps a list. If you want the attribute `start` of the first element use `hostvars[item].a.0.start`

Comment: Thanks, is that a must to use 0 ? can i use a wildcard to make sure it loop through all the list?

Comment: Yes. Use `hostvars[item].a|json_query('[].start')`. If you have other issues either [edit] the question, or open new one, and make it [mre].